# How to round subtracted values to two decimal places?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two values one having two decimal places. I would like the result of the subtracted values to always display two decimal places only. As you can see form the jsfiddle the two numbers in the example display an answer of more than two decimal places. How to I get the answer only two decimal places?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e23wfpj7/

HTML

```
<div class="numb-one">34.56</div>
<div class="numb-two">10</div>
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="total"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.click').on('click', function(){
    var numbOne = $('.numb-one').text();
    var numbTwo = $('.numb-two').text();
    var subtract = numbOne - numbTwo;

    $('.total').html('Total: '+subtract);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple uses `.toFixed(2)` on the

```
var subtract = (numbOne - numbTwo).toFixed(2);
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

[LiveDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/e23wfpj7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e23wfpj7/5/)

```
$('.total').html('Total: ' + Math.round(subtract * 100) / 100);
```

Comment: You're missing the `Math.round()` step.  You can see your method doesn't work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3g6p2L38/ when you actually give it results with more than two decimal places.

Comment: Opps! Sorry my bad and Thanks!